# How to create workspace using command line perforce

Tags: windows, file, batch-processing

I am newly using command line perforce . will you plaese tell me how to create workspace with example?

Comment: 1. This is a question for Superuser, not StackOverflow.
2. Searching Google would have immediately given you what you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Here is our documentation on how to create a workspace from the command line using the 'p4 client ' command:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-17566

REFERENCES

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/How-to-Script-Client-Workspace-Cloning

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html

http://www.perforce.com/resources/tutorials